# SQL Count and TOP at the same Query

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL database that contains table of Articles that is related to newspaper table by np_id .

**Article Table (id, title , date,newspaperID )**
**Newspaper Table ( newspaperID , name,logo)**

I want to get the List of the News Paper including the total Number articles for each and the Latest article for each Newspaper, I want the result as below :

**newspapre1 , Count of Total  articles ( 4 articles ) , "I am the latest article", 1/25/2015** 
**newspaper2,7 articles,"i am the latest in newspaper2",1/23/2015**

what is the best practice to do such query ?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: what if 2 articles have the same date and are the most recent? How will you chose which is newer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the id of the Article is an increasing number and not an uniqueidentifier or some other custom made id you can use this query.

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT Newspaper.newspaperid, 
       COUNT(1) as TotalArticles, 
       MAX(Article.Id) AS LastArticleId
FROM Newspaper
INNER JOIN Article ON Article.newspaperid = Newspaper.newspaperID
GROUP BY Newspaper.newspaperid
)
SELECT * FROM Article 
INNER JOIN cte ON Article.Id = cte.LastArticleId
```

If the article id is not an increasing number the query gets more complex and you'll need one of the following

[Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

also take a look here 
[Grouping and counting rows by value until it changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327566/grouping-and-counting-rows-by-value-until-it-changes/29328224#29328224)

If you use SQL Server 2012+ you may also find this read interesting
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx

Comment: That was amazing and good point for getting the max article id , but there was miss typing before the Inner Join must but ( from article inner join newspaper ). thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes sure, I just typed that directly in here will edit :)