# Grouping and counting rows by value until next row differs by more than a specified value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

The query I am trying to produce is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327566/grouping-and-counting-rows-by-value-until-it-changes), but instead of counting where it changes, I need to count up to the point the difference exceeds a specific value.

I have tried setting a flag where the date difference is more than 14 from the previous, but that then gives 2 records - one for when the difference is greater than 14, and 1 for the rest. As the ID can appear multiple times with different dates, I cannot then group that result.

e.g.
Data:

```
ID      Date
1A      2020-01-01
1A      2020-01-03
2B      2020-01-05
1A      2020-02-01
```

Result set to be:

```
ID      Date         Count
1A      2020-01-01   2
2B      2020-01-05   1
1A      2020-02-01   1
```

the criteria in this case being where the difference between the dates is more than 14 days

Tried:

```
SELECT [ID], [Date], 
case when datediff(dd,lag([Date]) over (partition by ID order by [Date]),[Date])>14
    then 1 else 0 end as CaseValue
FROM Table
where [Date]>'2020-02-01'
```

and

```
declare @CountValue bigint

SELECT [ID], [Date], 
@CountValue=@CountValue+case when datediff(dd,lag([Date]) over (partition by ID order by [Date]),[Date])>14
    then 1 else 0 end
FROM Table
where [Date]>'2020-02-01'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: For thing like this, you normally need iteration, which is slow. :/

Comment: I was also thinking of using a cursor, which would be equally slow :(

Comment: An rCTE would be faster than a `CURSOR` at least.